# how to achieve ChromeDevtoolsProtocol - CSS.getMatchedStylesForNode in the client

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

I have a client which would receive protocol "CSS.getMatchedStylesForNode" from ChromeDevtools.But I don't know how to receive this protocol. Please help.

Comment: It depends on the client. There are lots of existing libraries and the [documentation](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) itself.

Comment: Would you tell me the existing libraries please